# Why this c++ program not handling exception and giving core dump for negative numbers

Tags: c++, exception

While executing this program on gcc, its working fine for positive numbers. but it should not crash for negative numbers as exception is handled. But its giving core dump.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    double dX;
    cin >> dX;

    try
    {
        if (dX < 0.0)
            throw "Can not take sqrt of negative number";

       cout << "Going Good";
    }
    catch (char* strException)
    {
        cerr << "Error: " << strException << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're not throwing a `char*`, you're throwing a `const char*`.

Also, there already exists a pre-made exception class for this: [`std::range_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/range_error).

Answer (score 0):

You throw `char const*` and try to catch `char*`. String literals are strored in read-only memory, thus they can not be modified and should be pointed by pointer to constant `char`.